# How can I add plots with matlab2tikz in Latex? Package PGF Math Error: The function `thisrow' already exists. ]

Tags: latex

I want to export plots with matlab2tikz and paste them into latex. In matlab I exported the plots via matlab2tikz('plot4.tikz', 'width', '\linewidth', 'height', '0.4\linewidth', 'extraAxisOptions', 'align=right');.
In the following latex code I get the errors
Package PGF Math Error: The function `thisrow' already exists. ]
Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, nested axis environments are not supported. Pl (for example named nodes, see manual) to place it at the desired position. ]
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]. ]
How can I solve the errors? And how is the right way to export plots from matlab and import it in latex? I want to create a 2x2 subplot, and the plots should be right aligned so that the axes are the same with the next plot.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Einstellungen für den Subplot
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={width=0.4\linewidth}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[name=plot1]
                \input{plot1.tikz}
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[name=plot2,at={(plot1.south east)},anchor=south west]
                \input{plot2.tikz}
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[name=plot3,at={(plot1.below south west)},anchor=north west]
                \input{plot3.tikz}
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[name=plot4,at={(plot2.south east)},anchor=south west]
                \input{plot4.tikz}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Mein Subplot}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```